# How to put my url images into carousel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, carousel

I am getting URL images from API. I have stored the UR images into string. Here my problem I want to display that into carousel. I don't know how to do this. Below is my code that I have tried.

```
for(int i=0;i<hotelIMAges.count;i++ )
{
    NSDictionary *images=[hotelIMAges objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *Images= [images objectForKey:@"Imagepath"];
    [ImageARRAy addObject:Images];
} //Here I have stored all the images into string..(https://***.jpg)

Carousel *carousel = [[Carousel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,300, 262)];
[carousel setImages:ImagesARRAy];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to process **asynchronously** as your current approach can be a synchronous request and blocks the main thread until that download is complete.

Consider using `SDWebImage` and the `UIImageView` extension it adds to manage the image download and display. It also supports a placeholder image that you can supply to indicate that the download is in progress.

If your using any third party carousel check for asynchronous methods to display the images.I believe `setImages`: method must be for images that are stored locally inside app. Do let me know if you have any queries.

----EDITED----

Your Carousel is using synchronous method to display which blocks the main thread.
You can use SDWebImage for your purpose.
For this you need to download SDWebImage for asynchronous downloading of image.  You can download SDWebImage from link below. 
You can use it in your Carousel.h class as

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

modify your setup method with below line.

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.images[i]]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

For details refer github page of SDwebpage. DO let me know if you have any queries.
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-asynchronous-image-downloader-independently

Comment: I am using below two line carousel code after all the images where downloads ..I written it inside the button...Here my problem is I want my url images(https://somestrings.jpg) into (some string.jpg )format

Comment: Before I have used like this [carousel setImages:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hotel.jpg", @"hotel2.jpg", @"hotel3.jpg",@"hotel4.jpg",@"hotel5.jpg", nil]];  Now I getting the response in url format

Comment: are u using any third party library for Carousel. Do share me link if you do so.

Comment: developershubhra@gmail.com. BTW which third party library are u using??

Comment: @Kavitha i have updated my ans. Have a look and let me know if you have any quries.